# loading a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to load a text file into a dictionary and running into issues. The code below puts the input in a dictionary and then writes the dictionary to a text file for saving. I'm looking for a way to load that text file as a dictionary in order to have the `if` statement be able to search it. I'm sure I'm making this harder than it should be, but does anyone have some insight on loading the test.txt to the dict on program start?

```py
dict = {}

file = open('/python/test.txt', 'w')

while True:

    print("Enter stuff: ")
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    if name in dict:
        print(dict[name])

    else:
        print("don't have that, enter number for name")
        data = input()
        dict[name] = data

file.write(str(dict))

file.close()
```

test.txt contents:

> {'joe': '11', 'sue': '12', 'john': '13'}

Comment: How about using JSON format?

Comment: `dict` is a built-in dictionary constructor. Do not use this identifier for your variables.

Comment: Is your question about serialize-deserialize the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import json

data_dict = {}

file_1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
file_data = file_1.read()
if file_data:
    data_dict  = json.loads(file_data)
file_1.close()

file = open('test.txt', 'w')
while True:

    print("Enter stuff: ")
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    if name in data_dict:
        print(data_dict[name])

    else:
        print("don't have that, enter number for name")
        data = input()
        data_dict[name] = data


file.write(json.dumps(data_dict))
file.close()

print(data_dict, type(data_dict))
```

Comment: this seems to be doing the same thing as my code. the text file gets over written each time the program starts

i'm trying to have my entries saved in the text file and then loaded as a dictionary when the program starts. That way I can add entries and then the new and old entries will be saved upon exit. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider to import additional packages, you can use python [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function to write dictionary to file:

```
names_data = {}

while True:
    name = input(prompt="Enter stuff: ")
    if name == "":
        break
    elif name in names_data:
        print(names_data[name])
    else:
        data = input(prompt="don't have that, enter number for name: ")
        names_data[name] = data

with open("/python/test.txt", "w") as file:
    print(names_data, file=file)
```